# Find infimum and supremum of a set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So I've got a set $S = \bigg\{\frac{5 + n \cdot \cos(2x - 10) - 2n}{n} | $ n $\in \Bbb N,  \ x \in \Bbb (-5, -4)\bigg\}$.

I need to find its inf and sup.

I tried writing S differently and got this:

$S = \bigg\{\frac{n \cdot (\frac{5}{n} + \cos(2x - 10) - 2)}{n} |$ n $ \in \Bbb N,  \ x \in \Bbb (-5, -4)\bigg\}$.

Now, $S = \bigg\{\frac{5}{n} + \cos(2x - 10) - 2 |$ n $\in \Bbb N,  \ x \in \Bbb (-5, -4)\bigg\}$.

So, because of the fact that $x$ is from $(-5, -4)$, the expression

$\frac{5}{n} + \cos(-20) - 2 < \frac{5}{n} + \cos(2x - 10) - 2 < \frac{5}{n} + \cos(-18) - 2 $

Now, due to the fact that cos is an even function we have the following

$\frac{5}{n} + \cos(20) - 2 < \frac{5}{n} + \cos(2x - 10) - 2 < \frac{5}{n} + \cos(18) - 2 $

I'm stuck here. Even though I'm not even sure if any of it is correct.
If you have any hints, please tell me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the three parts of your function:

1. $\frac{5}{n}$
2. $\cos(2x-10)$
3. $-2$

The third part is constant. The first part resp. second part depend only on $n$ resp. $x$. But since the two variables do not occur in both terms, you can consider them independently. So how do you have to choose $n \in \mathbb N$ s.th. the whole term gets as small/big as possible? Similar: how do you have to choose $x \in (-5,-4)$ s.th. $\cos(2x-10)$ gets as small/big as possible? Don't forget the edge cases, i.e. it could be that for example $\cos(2x-10)$ has the greatest value for $x=-5$, that would be still possible, although $-5 \notin (-5,-4)$, since you are only interested in the infimum/supremum, not minimum/maximum.